# Как тащить за собой питон?

Tags: python, c++, linux

с++ программа вызывает питон скрипты через pybind, но питон там должен быть особенный ( с правильным набором библиотек ). На винде я просто копирую папку с питоном в папку с проектом -_-.
Как поступать с линуксом? есть ли там такой же (embeddable) питон, как на винде, чтобы его можно было положить в корень проекта, или я категорически делаю что-то не так?

Comment: Можно venv использовать чтобы свой питон и набор библиотек организовать.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan, надо чтобы при установке, скажем, через деб пакет, в софте был свой питон

Comment: В deb пакете указываете зависимость от питона нужной версии, и в инсталяционный скрипт включаете создание venv с установкой нужных пакетов.

Comment: @Vladimir Gamalyan,
 оу..., вы так делали? это хорошая практика?

Comment: Лучшая практика =) В принципе, как и на винде, можно бинарники питона сложить в отдельную папку вместе с библиотеками, в большинстве случаев будет нормально работать (в общем-то venv по сути и копирует питон из системы в отдельную папку).

Comment: А если интернета нету на стороне, который устанавливает софт?

Comment: Зависит от размаха проекта, можно и локальный репозиторий например развернуть на отдельной машине внутри предприятия. Можно вовнутрь deb пакета собрать все необходимое. Можно даже livecd (liveusb) со всем комплектом софта собрать и загружаться с него. Или вообще docker контейнер или образ виртуальной машины.

Comment: Къанонично будет через систему пакетов (deb+pip) все же сделать. Так вы снимите с себя все установочные нюансы (т.к. пакет сам знает как ему лучше на конкретной системе себя установить, что докачать и что запустить в процессе установки). Но если это какой-то внутренний продукт, то конечно смотрите как вам удобнее.

Comment: Делайте докер образ со всеми зависимостями. Создание пакетов - занятие крайне нетривиальное, а ковыряние с окружением - крайне ненадежное.

Comment: @user7860670, клиенту я тоже докер поставлю?

Comment: Да, распространяйте приложение в виде готового докер образа.

Comment: @user7860670, а можно про это где то прочитать?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/develop/

Comment: да также таскайте в папочке.

Comment: Докер-образ — это новомодный монстр тех, кто не смог в нормальную упаковку (rpm, deb, ...). Не делайте так, не портите себе карму.

Comment: flatpak сделай приложения своего.

Comment: @user7860670 создание пакета, как правило, это копирование нужных файлов в отдельную папку, заполнение простого конфига и запуск одной команды. На пару часов для новичка. Не сказал бы что это крайне нетривиально. Хотя с образом докера, согласен, меньше неожиданностей при распространении.

Comment: @xmikex тот же докер. ну чуть поменьше. тоже по сути копирование половины usr в отдельную папочку.

Comment: eri, я думал flatpak вообще одним файлом.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python после 3.9, возможно после 3.5 - точно не уверен, вполне портабельный:

Создай папочку, копирни сам язык:

```
mkdir python-portable
cd python-portable/
mkdir lib/ bin/
cp /usr/bin/python3 ./bin/
cp /usr/lib/libpython3.so ./lib/
```

Стандартные либы

```
cp -r /usr/lib/python3.9 ./lib/
```

Но выкинем site-packages чтоб не путаться (в убунтах есть ещё dist-packages):

```
rm ./lib/python3.9/site-packages -rf
mkdir ./lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Вот питон рабочий

```
./bin/python3
>>> import site
>>> site.PREFIXES
['/tmp/python-portable', '/tmp/python-portable']
>>> site.getsitepackages()
['/tmp/python-portable/lib/python3.9/site-packages']
```

Теперь менеджер либ, ставится очень легко:

```
./bin/python3 -m ensurepip
```

Если есть папка `site.getuserbase()`, то её временно переименуй, чтоб все зависимости упали в каталог `site-packages`:

```
mv  ~/.local/lib/python3.9  ~/.local/lib/python3.9.bak
```

И можно ставить свои зависимости:

```
./python3 -m pip install pybind11
ls lib/python3.9/site-packages/
```

Не забудь вернуть на место:

```
mv  ~/.local/lib/python3.9.bak  ~/.local/lib/python3.9
```

*П.С. Ваш питон не запустится на системах со старой glibc - если нужна поддержка убунты 16.04 ,например, то ставьте 16.04, там из исходников собираете нужную версию и установите его с префиксом в отдельной папочке - это будет проще, но дольше. Такая сборка запустится на большинстве линуксов. Это справедливо и для сишной части программы.*

Comment: Научите его лучше упаковке в пакет — это не сложно же.

Comment: кого научить? меня? я знаю как пакеты собирать, трабл возник какраз таки с питоном, как его транспортировать на линуксе. Джентельмен выше очень помог. Спасибо

Comment: я не понимаю минусующих. если не нравится этот метод по политическим причинам - напишите новый ответ с методом лучше и я вам поставлю плюс. тут же конкретный ответ на конкретный вопрос

Comment: "Почему наручники? Куда вы меня тащите? Я же только рассказал как сделать бомбу из подручных материалов!" :)))

Comment: Это путь в никуда. Уже в комментариях обсудили, зачем этот «ответ»? И да, тут не про политику.

Comment: Проприетаоное решение линковать к системному питону не рабочий вариант на практике. Вот возьмем например sbis плагин - там и qt и chromium и nginx лежат в папке. Вибер - qt в папочках. Еще смотри... нужен например минимум питон 3.6 и поддержка дистрибутивов с питоном 3.5 - бакпортирование питона 3.6 в такие ломает систему) если не ставить его как системный, то чем это отличается от копирования файлов?

Answer (score 6):

Предложенный выше вариант в корне неверен как идеологически, так и техничеки.

1. Питон и его библиотеки не будут сопровождаться (патчи безопасности, обновления). Точнее постольку-поскольку, лишь бы работало.
2. Система будет не в курсе, что гдето есть питон и его библиотеки. Будет мешать, например устанавливая другие версии библиотек в стандартные пути.
3. Непортабельно. Будет слабо переносимо между дистрибутивами из-за, например, упомянутых выше разных версий glibc
4. Будет установлено куда-то мимо [стандартных путей](http://files.rsdn.org/28760/Linux-file-system-hierarchy-Linux-file-structure-optimized.jpg) и образует свой root, для которого админам придётся настраивать свой бекап, свой логротейт и так далее.

Как правильно?

1. Ориентироваться на текущий stable питон в выбранных дистрибутивах. Точно так-же и с его библиотеками.
2. Свой код опакетить, указав в зависимостях пакетов нужные версии питона и либ.
3. Поднять свои репозитории, куда выкладывать свои пакеты, дав людям возможность не только просто подключать репозиторий и устанавливать одной стандартной командой всё нужное, но и обновлять штатно.

Смысл в том, что в системе уже есть манагер пакетов, который занимается установкой/удалением софта и зависимостей. Не нужно заставлять человека быть манагером пакетов, выкачивая руками, распаковывая и что там еще делать надо. Не нужно даже заставлять устанавливать второй/третий манагер пакетов (pip, npm, cargo и так далее). Они будут мешать друг другу, что со временем выльется в непонятные сбои.

Со стороны разработки - вам же не придётся сопровождать питон и его окружение. Не придётся всё это своевременно обновлять, патчить, компилировать и так далее.   Пусть каждый занимается своим проектом. Вы - своим, разрабы питона - своим, разрабы дистрибутива - дистрибутивом и так далее.

Я всё сказал.

Comment: интересно как поставлять приложение, на машину, на которой нету интернета (по соображении безопасности). Как тот человек будет обновлять или скачивать питон? мы выбрали такой способ поставки дистрибутива не потому что так проще, а потому что по другому никак (. Решения которые описывались выше , они хорошие, но не подходят... вот так вот :(

Comment: Вкорне неверно делать тоже самое что делает venv, cxfreeze, pyinstaller?

Comment: 2. Нет, в стандартные пути ничего лишнего не встанет.

Comment: 3. Портабельно настолько же насколько портабельно материнское приложение на плюсах. Легко переносится вверх

Comment: 4. Бэкапить что? Логи чего? Само приложение на си++ решает куда ложить данные и логи.

Comment: На машину без интернета точно так же, как и обновлять на ней-же дистрибутив. Принести из интернета репозиторий на диске.

Comment: venv, cxfreeze, pyinstaller предназначены для облегчения разработки, а не для production. Докер, с некоторой натяжкой, так-же.

Comment: В стандартные пути приедут другие версии питоне/пакетов. И это может начать конфликтовать с песочницей при импорте.

Comment: Само приложение не должно решать куда класть логи и данные.  Идеально вместо логов - stdout/stderr, и принимать в комстроке параметром путь к файлу настроек, в котором уже указать подробности, в том числе и куда сложить данные.

Comment: не будет ничего конфликтовать. Если уж очень надо, то можно поправить sys.path

Comment: Портабельно до тех пор, пока дистрибутив мажор не сменит, например. Или пока луна в Овне. Не стоит вместо разрабов дистрибутивов придумывать будет ли оно работать или нет. Ориентируйтесь не на археологию и пре-альфа, а на стабильные пакеты, уже используемые в дистрибутивах.

Comment: Угу. У себя сиспатх подправили. И это сделали ещё трое разрабов, но уже в своих библиотеках. но в другую сторону. Поймите, то что вы предлагает подойдет для разработки, но никак не для прода.

Comment: Кстати это не ответ. Тут не содержится решения)

Comment: Это тот самый случай когда на вопрос "как отстрелить себе ногу?" следует ответить "Друг, что у тебя случилось? Давай помогу сделать правильно"